# How do I obtain id of calendar programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a calendar with a specific name and summary and get the id Google is assigning to it programmatically.

I know how to do it manually, I just want to have a way to create the calendar and later post events referring to it by id.

Using the script below, as shown in CalendarApp documentation, provides a number of calendars containing the text 'US Holidays'.

```js
// Gets the public calendar named "US Holidays".
 var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('US Holidays');
 Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);
```

I have replaced:

`Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length);`

With:

`Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.getId());`

But I get:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object Calendar. (line 22,
>   file "")

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `getCalendarsByName()` returns an array; that's why `calendars` had a `length` property. The `getId()` method applies to an *individual* calendar object, e.g. calendars[0].getId().

**Tip:** When you're writing code in the Google Apps Script editor, watch for and *take advantage of* the [auto-completion feature](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#using_autocomplete). For instance, starting with the example you've shown, position your cursor just before the dot following `calendars` on the second line. If you now press <kbd>.</kbd>, autocomplete will pop up a list of properties and methods that apply to the object before the `.`. See the video below: Since `calendars` does not have a `getId()` method, it will **not** be one of the items in the list, which is a good clue. (Those are all Array methods and properties.)

[image]

#### Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Gets the public calendar named "US Holidays".
  var calendars = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('US Holidays');
  Logger.log('Found %s matching calendars.', calendars.length.toString() );

  for (var i=0; i<calendars.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('calendar[%s] id: %s.', i.toString(), calendars[i].getId() );
  }
}
```

#### Logs:

```
[15-10-16 14:46:58:664 EDT] Found 1 matching calendars.
[15-10-16 14:46:58:666 EDT] calendar[0] id: en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com.
```

(You might notice that I didn't *actually* test with the US Holiday calendar!)